# Google Amp 403 Forbidden error when testing endpoint from playground

Tags: java, amp-html

I keep getting a 403 forbidden error when trying to test my api endpoint from the Google amp playground. I tried adding all of the response headers that amp requires but I still get the error. These are the headers i have on the api response, am I missing anything?

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: https://amp.gmail.dev
access-control-allow-source-origin: https://www.example.com
access-control-expose-headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin
amp-access-control-allow-source-origin: amp@gmail.dev
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

And the form submission error in the console:

```
log.js:251 [amp-form] Form submission failed: Error: HTTP error 403​​​
    at bb (https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js:28:169)
    at Ya.f.createError (https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js:23:257)
    at https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js:141:409
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at jg (https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js:141:344)
    at https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js:143:267
```

Answer (score -1):

Try turning off recaptcha, most likely it returns the status of 'spam' which causes an error.